# I can't reduce the amount of rain drops falling from the ceiling

Tags: python, pygame

I have been making this game in which you are this block that has to dodge bullets, so I added this code that I found in the book that I have called "Python Hunting" this code allowed me to create my bullets class and add the bullets to the game. But I have been having trouble, the code works pretty well and I only have to include death for the player and a mini menu at the start, but I can't do it because there are way too many bullets and I want to fix that before doing anything else.

So I've found a way to reduce these bullets, but not enough, it's on line 58 (with the '''for i in range(1):''') and it allowed me to reduced them by a third, I tried using floats but it doesn't work. It still creates too many bullets. I also tried reducing the speed of the '''while''' loop, but sure enough it created less at a time but it also slowed them down and even made them really laggy it's horrible. So I don't know what to do.

Right here is the code I used. Sorry but I put everything in it because I didn't know what was important and what wasn't and so I thought I would play safe and put it all in. I put comments on sections of which object the program affects.

'''

```
import pygame, time, random, sys
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()


clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.display.set_caption("Dodge the bullet")
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((800, 600))
screen.fill((0, 0, 0))
font = pygame.font.Font(None, 54)
font_color = pygame.Color('springgreen')

class Bullets:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.speed = 8
    def move(self):
        self.y += self.speed

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.line(screen, (255, 255, 255), (self.x, self.y), (self.x,self.y+5), 3)

    def off_screen(self):
        return self.y > 800

class Player():

    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 380
        self.y = 535
        self.speed = 5
    def moveRight(self):
        self.x = self.x + self.speed

    def moveLeft(self):
        self.x = self.x - self.speed

    def moveUp(self):
        self.y = self.y - self.speed

    def moveDown(self):
        self.y = self.y + self.speed

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [self.x,  self.y,   20,   20])

    def hit_by(self, bullet):
        return pygame.Rect(self.x, self.y, 20, 20).collidepoint((bullet.x, bullet.y))

class Top():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

    def rain(self):
        for i in range(1):
            bullets.append(Bullets(random.randint(self.x, self.x+800), self.y))

    def draw(self):
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (255, 255, 255), [self.x,  self.y,   1,   600])



player = Player()
bullets = []
top = Top()

passed_time = 0
timer_started = False
done = False


while 1:
    clock.tick(60)
    pressed_keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            sys.exit()
    screen.fill((0, 0, 0))

    #Player
    player.draw()
    if pressed_keys[K_RIGHT]:
        player.moveRight()
    if pressed_keys[K_LEFT]:
        player.moveLeft()
    if pressed_keys[K_UP]:
        player.moveUp()
    if pressed_keys[K_DOWN]:
        player.moveDown()

    #Timer
    if pressed_keys[K_SPACE]:
        timer_started = not timer_started
        if timer_started:
            start_time = pygame.time.get_ticks()
    if timer_started:
        passed_time = pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time

    text = font.render(str(passed_time/1000), True, font_color)
    screen.blit(text, (50, 50))

    #Top
    top.draw()
    top.rain()

    #Bullets
    #bullets.append(Bullets())

    i = 0
    while i < len(bullets):
        bullets[i].move()
        bullets[i].draw()
        flag = False
        if bullets[i].off_screen():
            flag = True
        if player.hit_by(bullets[i]):
            flag = True
            last_hit_time = time.time()
        if flag == True:
            del bullets[i]
            i -= 1
        i+= 1

    pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

'''

I expected something that would reduce the amount of bullets by a fair amount but I don't know whether that is possible or not. As you might see there are too many bullets for the player to dodge.

Thanks a lot in advance,
Hope to here from you guys/girls soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `.count` attribute to the class `Top`. Increment the counter in the method `rain`. Only spawn `Bullet` objects, when the counter exceeds a certain limit:

e.g.

```py
class Top():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0
        self.count = 0

    def rain(self):
        self.count += 1 
        if self.count == 3:
            self.count = 0
            bullets.append(Bullets(random.randint(self.x, self.x+800), self.y))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that was the solution, if you want I could add your name to the menu so you get a little more "reputation", even though you won't get much. Don't hesitate to ask. It really helped me;